# iOS UISlider knob ghosting when returning to view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uislider

In a tableviewcell I have a UISlider. If I move the slider knob, go back to my previous view, and then return back to the table view, the knob on the slider returned back to zero but I see a "ghosting" of the knob where I had previously moved the slider too.

I clear the context view on the slider object in cellForRowAtIndexPath: and reload the table in viewDidAppear.

Anyone know how to fix this? It's quite annoying. I put the slider code down below if that helps at all.

```
        // Setup slider
        CGRect sliderFrame = CGRectMake(15, 56, 230, 0);
        UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:sliderFrame];
        slider.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
        [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderUpdated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderStopped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:slider];
        [slider release];
```

I appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: You do not have any check to see if you have already drawn a slider/you make no attempt to grab a previously drawn slider. My guess is that you are simply drawing a new slider over the old one, therefore you can see the old slider in the background that may well be in a different position.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response.

That makes sense, but how do you check for that? Is the best way to actually loop through all the subviews of the cell to see if they exist, and if they don't create them otherwise just update them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that you are creating a new `UISlider` over the old `UISlider` which gives the ghosting effect.

Two possible solutions

1. Tag the `UISlider` when you add it to a cell.
2. Subclass `UITableViewCell` and add a `UISlider` to it's content view and keep a reference to it with an ivar.

To do 1 simply tag the `UISlider` when you add it to the contentView. Then when you get a cell again you try getting the view back first or you create it a fresh.

```
const int sliderViewTag = 99;

UISlider *slider = [cell.contentView viewWithTag:sliderViewTag];

if (!slider) {
  CGRect sliderFrame = CGRectMake(15, 56, 230, 0);
  slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:sliderFrame];
  slider.clearsContextBeforeDrawing = YES;
  [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderUpdated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
  [slider addTarget:self action:@selector(sliderStopped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [cell.contentView addSubview:slider];
  [slider release]; slider = nil;
}
```

Although 2 is a little more involved it is my preferred method but I am sure there are some great examples of how to do it. There is some great docs by Apple so check them out [Table View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7) specifically look at the section `A Closer Look at Table-View Cells`

Comment: Thanks so much Paul. This was my first attempt at programmatically adding in subviews, and so I just kind of assumed that the OS would take care of reusing the subviews as opposed to drawing over them with new ones.